# C# Save PPT Shape (msoPicture) as Image w/ Office.Interop

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I have a PPT slide deck with multiple images. I am iterating through each slide and each shape. I would like to save each shape of type msoPicture as an Image:

```
            foreach (PPT.Slide slide in pptDoc.Slides)
            {
                foreach (PPT.Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
                {
                    if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
                    {

                        Image img;
                        //???? Save shape as image
                        img.Save(filename);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`Shape.Export()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.export(v=office.14).aspx) to create an image from an individual shape.

For example like this:

```
foreach (PPT.Slide slide in pptDoc.Slides)
{
    foreach (PPT.Shape shape in slide.Shapes)
    {
        if (shape.Type == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoShapeType.msoPicture)
        {
            shape.Export(filename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.PpShapeFormat.ppShapeFormatPNG);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if it can be saved to a stream, rather than the file system?

Comment: @JDR AFAIK this is not possible using COM Automation (i.e. using `Microsoft.Interop`). But it should be possible when using a library for working with the files directly, for example like `OpenXML` (though this might be a bit more complicated than using COM Automation since the office file formats are quite complex)

Comment: Thanks, I will probably just stick to the file system since, after looking into this a bit more, it appears to be a lot more hassle than it is worth saving a tiny bit on IO.