# Powerpoint "Save As Picture" from C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

My question is pretty similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442659/c-sharp-save-ppt-shape-msopicture-as-image-w-office-interop) and I'm afraid the answer is the same... I want to save all the shapes/images on a slide as a single png (or jpeg). Programmatically, I get as far as

```
slide.Shapes.SelectAll();
```

but don't see a way to save as image. Is this possible? If not, any other suggestions, hopfully w/ examples? (not VBA - I need to automate the whole conversion)

There was a reference to OpenXML in the other post, but I'm not even sure how to pull that in.

Comment: Is it just the images from the page? Or the entire page with all content? You could do a Save As... to either of those formats. One file per page.

Comment: I'd strongly prefer to only save the images (to avoid the surrounding whitespace). My fall-back is `slide.Export();`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'd do this in C# but I'd guess that you'd make use of the same methods as you would with VBA, where you can do:

```
Activewindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Export( "c:\temp\delete-me.jpg",ppShapeFormatJPG)
```

ppShapeFormatJPG is a PowerPoint constant, a VBA Long = 1; IIRC that'd be an Integer in C#.

The method also can take two more optional parameters, scalewidth and scaleheight, which govern the width and height of the exported image in undocumented ways. By default, no parms supplied, I get exports at 72 dpi. Larger numbers result in higher pixel count exports but distorted proportions. I'm sure there's some strange logic to it, but it escapes me; all hints welcome!

There's a third optional parm, ExportMode. In my tests, it makes no difference whether you supply it or not, and if you do, which of the available values you choose.

Comment: Thanks. Anyone have any ideas a way to create & run a VBA macros from C#/.NET world? I need a general purpose script to process 1 or more PPT files.

Comment: Since .ShapeRange.Export is part of the PowerPoint object model and not a VBA-specific feature, I'd think you could access it directly from C# the same way you'd use slide.Export. But while I can read a little Spanish, I can't speak it to save my life any more; likewise C#.  ;-)

Comment: I only dabble in this stuff, but as I understand it the objects & methods available from the outside (to C# or VB .NET through COM) are a subset of what VBA apps inside Powerpoint can see. I couldn't find anything that looked like `Selection` or `ShapeRange`.